# Using boost unordered map

Tags: performance, boost, unordered-map

Guys, I am using dynamic programming approach to solve a problem. Here is a brief overview of the approach

1. Each value generated is identified using 25 unique keys.
2. I use the **boost::hash_combine** to generate the **seed** for the hash table using these 25 keys.
3. I store the values in a hash table declared as

   `boost::unordered_map<Key_Object, Data_Object, HashFunction> hashState;`
4. I did a time profiling on my algorithm and found that nearly **95%** of the run time is spent towards retrieving/inserting data into the hash table.
5. These were the details of my hash table

   `hashState.size()                1880`

   `hashState.load_factor()         0.610588`

   `hashState.bucket_count()        3079`

   `hashState.max_size()            805306456`

   `hashState.max_load_factor()     1`

   `hashState.max_bucket_count()    805306457`

I have the following two questions

1. Is there anything which I can do to improve the performance of the Hash Table's insert/retrieve operations?
2. C++ STL has hash_multimap which would also suit my requirement. How does boost libraries **unordered_map** compare with **hash_multimap** in terms of **insert/retrieve performance**.

Comment: Check bucket size distribution.  It might be that your hash function is bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your hash function is not the culprit, the best you can do is probably using a different map implementation.  Since your keys are quite large, using `unordered_map` from [Boost.Intrusive library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/intrusive.html) might be the best option.  Alternatively, you could try closed hashing: [Google SparseHash](http://code.google.com/p/google-sparsehash/) or [MCT](https://launchpad.net/libmct), though profiling is certainly needed because closed hashing is recommended when elements are small enough.  (SparseHash is more established and well tested, but MCT doesn't need those `set_empty()`/`set_deleted()` methods).

EDIT:

I just noticed there is no intrusive map in the Boost library I mentioned, only set and multiset.  Still, you can try the two closed hashing libraries.

EDIT 2:

STL `hash_map` is not standard, it is probably some extension and not portable across compilers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the hash function you are using is not the bottleneck?
Which time percentage takes the hash function?
Can you do the same test and replace the insert/retrievals by a simple call to the hash.

Comment: The hash function which generates the seed value takes 60% of the computation time. It does a boost::hash_combine on 25 key values. I tried using a simple hash key, but it takes a very long time to retrieve the value. FYI, I am looking at inserting and retrieving > 100,000 values into the hash table

Comment: Which one spent less time, boost::hash_combine on 25 key values or simple hash?

Comment: For the simple hash, the time spent on hashing was a mere 1% on the entire run time of the algorithm. But the algorithm as such took a very long time to run. And I believe that it was because of the more time spent in retrieving/inserting values as a result of too many collisions!